# inline UiPickerView in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, inline, uipickerview

I am using more than two inline picker views (Not UIDatePickerView) and it's working fine with all transition but what my problem is its mixing the data sources value and shows both mixed value.

I have just used Apple's sample for an inline datepicker for checking.

I have `data1PickerView` with its own Two `DataSource` named as `data1` and `data2`.

My code is as follows when I open the pickerView on tableViewCell didSelect

```
data1=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
data2=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",nil];

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    if(indexPath.row==1){
        isData1=TRUE;
        isData2=FALSE;
    }

    else if(indexPath.row==2){

        isData2=TRUE;
        isData1=FALSE;
    }
    if (cell.reuseIdentifier == kDateCellID)
    {
        if (EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER)
            [self displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        else
            [self displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
/*! Reveals the date picker inline for the given indexPath, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // display the date picker inline with the table content
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    BOOL before = NO;   // indicates if the date picker is below "indexPath", help us determine which row to reveal
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        before = self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row;
    }

    BOOL sameCellClicked = (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row);

    // remove any date picker cell if it exists
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = nil;
    }

    if (!sameCellClicked)
    {
        // hide the old date picker and display the new one
        NSInteger rowToReveal = (before ? indexPath.row - 1 : indexPath.row);
        NSIndexPath *indexPathToReveal = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToReveal inSection:0];

        [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPathToReveal];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathToReveal.row + 1 inSection:0];
    }

    // always deselect the row containing the start or end date
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // inform our date picker of the current date to match the current cell
    [self updateDatePicker];
}


// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if(isData1)
    return data1.count;
    else if(isData2)
        return data2.count;
    else
        return 0;
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    if(isData1)
        return [data1 objectAtIndex:row];
    else if(isData2)
        return [data2 objectAtIndex:row]
        ;
else
    return @"";
}

- (void)toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tblRegister beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];

    // check if 'indexPath' has an attached date picker below it
    if ([self hasPickerForIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        // found a picker below it, so remove it
        [tblRegister deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else
    {

        // didn't find a picker below it, so we should insert it
        [tblRegister insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [tblRegister endUpdates];
}
```

can any one please tell me what cause that my data1 datasource shwoing values with data2 Datasource and vice a versa as per following image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code where you are setting the datasources for data1pickerView?

Comment: Have you checked the data source of UIPickerView, you  have used array or NSSet or dictionary? I am asking because in your images the data are not in same order? And i guess, you may have appending datasource of both PickerView without removing previous value

Comment: @Janmenjaya am having two diffrent array for datasource please check ma upadted answer.

Comment: Can we please see your method: [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPathToReveal] ?

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is that the value of your `isData1` and `isData2` booleans are not what you expect them to be when  the UI is rendering those picker views. I expect that if you place a breakpoint on your `- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component` method you will see something awry.